# Session compare with Enum in C# View page

Tags: c#

says in my controller I have created this session,

```
public enum UserRoles
{
    Customer, Admin
}
```

Session["roles"] = UserRoles.Admin;

and in my view page, how to I compare the session with UserRoles enum? Below code doesn't work.

```
if (Session["roles"] == UserRoles.Admin)
{
   // show something
}
```

Comment: You need to cast it to userroles enum and compare it

Comment: @Justcode this should be posted as answer

Comment: can show the code? @justcode

Comment: You probably should not be doing it from a view. If you are sure you must, qualify the enum better (e.g. `== MyProject.SomeNamespace.UserRoles.Admin`).

Comment: ya it is not the best solution for now. should use things like ASP.NET Identity. just trying out this old school session for now.

Comment: In my controller now,                     `Session["roles"] = (int)UserRoles.Admin;` and then in my view, `if ((int)Session["roles"] == (int)MaybankATMSystem.Models.UserRoles.Admin)` . it works for this for the the enum integer value, 0 and 1

Comment: @Steve, I added my answer below its standard way of casting your session to enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your session value to enum `UserRoles` like

```
if ((UserRoles)Session["roles"] == UserRoles.Admin)
{
    // show something
}
```

Or more readable you can take result of cast into variable of enum and then use in your `if` like,

```
UserRoles userRoles = (UserRoles)Session["roles"];

if (userRoles == UserRoles.Admin)
{
    // show something
}
```

Comment: `if ((MaybankATMSystem.Models.UserRoles)Session["roles"] == MaybankATMSystem.Models.UserRoles.Admin)` thanks. works also.

Comment: Yes absolutely, you can use anyone from above, the second is for your understanding purpose and more readable :) **Glad to hear and welcome**

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use `Enum.Parse` if you are sure that the value will always be set as `UserRoles` type:

```
if (Enum.Parse<UserRoles>(Session["roles"].ToString()) == UserRoles.Admin)
```

If not, you can use `Enum.TryParse` like this:

```
UserRole sessionRole; 
if (!Enum.TryParse<UserRole>(Session["roles"].ToString(), out sessionRole)) 
{
    //handle the case when incorrect UserRole value is set into the Session["roles"].
}
// use the sessionRole variable to check for the current session role variable
```

**EDIT**

Do not use this in the view, use a ViewModel class and add a variable there whether the user is an admin or a particular role you need to check.

[More info on Enum.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Enum_TryParse__1_System_String___0__)
[More info on Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#definition)

Comment: Why would you want to parse the value given the OP's code of `Session["roles"] = UserRoles.Admin`?

Comment: Because `Session["roles"]` returns an `object`

Comment: And that object should be cast to an enum value, [not parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3750986/11683).