# When I am trying to unbox this object p.objPrice to integer type I am getting an Exception: Specified cast is not valid?

Tags: c#, .net

When I am trying to unbox this object `p.objPrice` to integer type I am getting an exception: `Specified cast is not valid`?

```
class Product
    {
        public object objProductID { get; set; }
        public object objProductName { get; set; }
        public object objPrice { get; set; }
        public object objQuantity { get; set; }
        public double amountPayable { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product p = new Product();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value for Product Id:");
        p.objProductID = Console.ReadLine();
        string prodID = (string)p.objProductID;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value for Product Name:");
        p.objProductName = Console.ReadLine();
        string prodName = (string)p.objProductName;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value for Price");
        p.objPrice = Console.ReadLine();
        int prodPrice = (int)p.objPrice; // getting exception Specified cast is not valid.

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value for Quantity:");
        p.objQuantity = Console.ReadLine();
        int prodQuantity = (int)p.objQuantity;// getting exception Specified cast is not valid.


        p.amountPayable = prodQuantity * prodPrice;
        Console.WriteLine($"The amount payable is: {p.amountPayable}");




        Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Unboxing requires the type to match _exactly_. However, `objPrice` contains a string, not an int, hence the error. What are you trying to do? Why put an object there? Why not directly put an int? Then at least you'd know you need to use something like `int.Parse`.

Comment: Thank u so much it worked, I forgot to convert string to int32 while taking the value. This code is a lab assignment regarding boxing and unboxing that's why I was putting an Object there.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse them to an integer using the `int.Parse()` method.
Make sure to use the `ToString()` method inside `int.Parse()`

```
int prodPrice = int.Parse(p.objPrice.ToString());  
int prodQuantity = int.Parse(p.objQuantity.ToString());
```

If you don't know the difference between cast and parse, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750937/cast-versus-parse) StackOverflow question.